# How to get last word of the URL (Laravel 5.1)

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get the last word of this URL:

```
http://localhost:8888/articles/tags/Europa
```

How could I make this in Laravel ? with this `{{URL::current()}}` I'm getting full URL. I have tried `{{URL::current().split('/').last}}` but then I get error: `Function split() is deprecated`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and use `preg_split()` instead

Example:

```
$var = 'http://localhost:8888/articles/tags/Europa';
$var = preg_split("/\//", 'http://localhost:8888/articles/tags/Europa');
array_pop($var ); //removes last
```

**Update**

I can't delete this because it is the accepted answer but please see [josh088's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31306472/4781925)

Comment: I tried it like this. Is this correct ? `{{URL::current().preg_split('/').last}}` I'm getting this error: `preg_split() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given`

Comment: @feknaz There's better ways of going about this, see josh008's answer. Please change that to the accepted answer so I can remove this :)

Answer (score 7):

You can also use segment method of the Request class.

```
$var = Request::segment(3);
```

This will capture the 3rd segment of the URI according to the API docs:
http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_segment

Comment: @aethergy updated